# How to fix "Try running with errors" for GET JSON and create DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to GET JSON data, extract "pull_request_contributors" add it to the DF and set the index.

**I get the error:**

```
KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'pull_request_contributors' is not always present"
```

**Code**

```
cg = CoinGeckoAPI()

ts = '01-01-2017'
cs = 'bitcoin'

# get data
result = cg.get_coin_history_by_id(cs, ts)

#pull_request_contributors
df_pr = pd_json.json_normalize(data, 
                            record_path='developer_data', 
                            meta=['pull_request_contributors']).set_index(ts)
```

**JSON:**

```
{'community_data': {'facebook_likes': 40055,
  'reddit_accounts_active_48h': '4657.4',
  'reddit_average_comments_48h': 186.5,
  'reddit_average_posts_48h': 3.75,
  'reddit_subscribers': 1014816,
  'twitter_followers': 64099},
 'developer_data': {'closed_issues': 3845,
  'commit_count_4_weeks': 245,
  'forks': 22024,
  'pull_request_contributors': 564,
  'pull_requests_merged': 6163,
  'stars': 36987,
  'subscribers': 3521,
  'total_issues': 4478}...
```

I expected df:

```
date        bitcoin 
01-01-2017  564
```

Comment: did you try doing what the error suggests?

Comment: @Chris it's always present, I don't know why giving me this error. Maybe my code is wrong?